# Error with loading tensorboard in Google colab

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, model

I'm facing issue with tensorboard loading in Google Colab. I tried to uninstall and then install it again but no sucess. i'm sharing the code and the error.

```
!pip install tensorboard
```

```
%load_ext tensorboard
```

```
log_folder = 'log1'
```

```
callbacks = TensorBoard(log_dir= log_folder, histogram_freq= 1)
```

```
model.fit(train_X, train_y, validation_data = (test_X, test_y),callbacks= callbacks,verbose= 0, epochs = 20)
```

```
%tensorboard --logdir = '/content/log1'  I tried withour quotes as well i.e /content/log1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ioxa.png)

I tried to load tensorboard and tried Uninstall and then reinstall

Answer (score 3):

"=" between `--logdir` and `<PATH>` appears to be the problem here. Use something like `--logdir log1`

Answer (score 0):

try to create access to the target directory that is required for the logging and accumulating functions. Oneway to save CPU memory is to use disk space and that is why summarized functions are working after it updates.

Sample: Callback function with updates frequency and the icon examples.

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio

from datetime import datetime

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
PATH = os.path.join('F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors\\train\\Pikaploy', '*.tif')
PATH_2 = os.path.join('F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors\\train\\Candidt Kibt', '*.tif')
files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH)
files_2 = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH_2)

list_file = []
list_file_actual = []
list_label = []
list_label_actual = [ 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt' ]
list_image_greyscales = []
for file in files.take(5):
    image = tf.io.read_file( file )
    image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image, index=0)
    list_file_actual.append(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [32,32], method='nearest')
    list_file.append(image)
    list_image_greyscales.append(tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image[:,:,0:3]))
    list_label.append(1)
    
for file in files_2.take(5):
    image = tf.io.read_file( file )
    image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image, index=0)
    list_file_actual.append(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [32,32], method='nearest')
    list_file.append(image)
    list_image_greyscales.append(tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image[:,:,0:3]))
    list_label.append(9)
    
checkpoint_path = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_DataSets_01.h5"
log_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)
    
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(tf.cast(list_file, dtype=tf.int64), shape=(10, 1, 32, 32, 4), dtype=tf.int64),tf.constant(list_label, shape=(10, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64)))

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Callback
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
tb_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir, update_freq=1, histogram_freq=1)

class custom_callback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        if( logs['accuracy'] >= 0.95 ):
            self.model.stop_training = True
    
custom_callback = custom_callback()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( 32, 32, 4 )),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=3., variance=2.),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=4., variance=6.),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((128, 225)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96, return_sequences=True, return_state=False)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(192, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(
    learning_rate=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07,
    name='Nadam'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=False,
    reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO,
    name='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])

# Creates a file writer for the log directory.
file_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(log_dir  + "\\" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") )

# Using the file writer, log the reshaped image.
with file_writer.as_default():
    for i in range(10):
        tf.summary.image("Training data", tf.constant( list_image_greyscales[i], shape=(1,32,32,1) ), step=i)
        tf.summary.scalar("Training data label", data=float(i), step=i)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit( dataset, batch_size=100, epochs=10, callbacks=[tb_callback, custom_callback] )
model.save_weights(checkpoint_path)

plt.figure(figsize=(5,2))
plt.title("Actors recognitions")
for i in range(len(list_file)):
    img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(
        list_file[i],
        data_format=None,
        scale=True
    )
    img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
    img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)
    predictions = model.predict(img_array)
    score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])
    plt.subplot(5, 2, i + 1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(list_file_actual[i])
    plt.xlabel(str(round(score[tf.math.argmax(score).numpy()].numpy(), 2)) + ":" +  str(list_label_actual[tf.math.argmax(score)]))
    
plt.show()

input('...')

### tensorboard --logdir="F:\models\checkpoint\test_tf_tensorboard_2\\"
```

Output: Tensorboard training and remarkable data.

- [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfNF9.png)
- [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBcTl.png)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error. Assignment operator was creating the problem, when I deleted the = it worked

%tensorboard --logdir '/content/log1'

Comment: This answer is already suggested above. If it solves your problem, please accept that answer.